# Why is lookup table forced to be keyed for left join in kdb

Tags: kdb

1. What are the benefits keeping the lookup table as keyed for left join in kdb?Does it provide performance benefits/memory benifits and how?
   As I have below table:

```
    t:([]sym:6?`GOOG`AMZN`IBM`AAPL; px:6?10.) /- source table

    kt:([sym:`IBM`AAPL`GOOG`AMZN]; vol:4?10000) /- lookup table

    t lj kt
```

2. Are the same benefits applicable for asof join as well because I have read in Q for Mortals **"There is no requirement for any of the join columns to be keys but the join will be faster on keys."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [keyed table](https://code.kx.com/q4m3/8_Tables/#841-keyed-table) is a dictionary mapping of keyed records to tables of values. Joining with a keyed table is, therefore, a dictionary lookup, which is inherently faster in kdb. The matching columns are used to simply index into the second table.